# .NET 6 : Keeping a value in memory and comparing it with the input value in web api

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, session-state, webapi

I want to keep a code in the session and compare when the user submits the code, in .NET 6 (Not Api) I used session, but I use the same configuration in Web Api, it gives an error?

I searched a lot but could not find a suitable answer!!

If the session cannot be used in Web Api, what is the best solution to save the value except the database?

Program.Cs

```
builder.Services.AddSession(option =>{
option.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
option.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
```

and :

```
app.UseSession();
```

When the project is executed, the following error is displayed

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some example code and an example of the error it's giving you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configure-session-state) the framework-provided session state management uses `IDistributedCache` as a backing store for session, so you need to add one:

```cs
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
```

Note that default registration (i.e. one above) actually is not distributed and   actually uses in-memory cache.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code and it worked correctly. Can it be used on a real server?

Comment: @AliKhansari yes, but you need to understand it's limitations - session will not be transfered between app instances (if you have several).

Comment: Do you think there is a more suitable solution? Actually, I want to use it to send the activation code

Comment: @AliKhansari you can 1) use one of the actually [distributed implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-7.0#establish-distributed-caching-services) 2) use sticky session 3) skip session and use some unique id to be send with the code (i.e. when user request activation code you send back to the UI some id so it would be send back with the code) and store uid+code pair in database.

Comment: Why does the session value become null in the next action?

Comment: @AliKhansari have no idea. Check if you are sending session cookie back.

Comment: I send the request with React and once I return the code, it is displayed in the React view, but in the next action, I set a breakpoint and it becomes null.!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a distributed cache that is not configured in your application. See
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-a-distributed-cache-in-asp-net-core on how to configure the distributed cache. However, that might be an overkill for what you are trying to achieve. You may just need to use session variables. See
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state#session-state for the different ways to achieve that.